# Was there a question on punctuation?

Tags: support

I *thought* that there was a question on punctuation and maths on the main site; however, when I went to look for it I couldn't find it.  Has it been deleted, or did it get lost in the database swindle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original link to that question was:

[Can super/sub-scripts bind more tightly than macro expansion?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431/should-one-punctuate-after-an-equation)

A totally different question is pointed by that same link. I'm afraid that the original question is now lost in the realm of lost questions :(

Comment: Given that it exists already on mathoverflow, I'm not too worried about its disappearance.  I wanted to refer to it, that was all, but as I couldn't find it I had to refer to the one on MO.

Answer (score 1):

I was the author of [one question about puctuation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431/should-one-punctuate-after-an-equation), and did not delete it! Surely something weird has happened there!

Comment: There was a database glitch yesterday morning and some stuff got lost, I guess that this was one of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to repost it, please [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6675) to it.